# Unexpected behaviour of multicolumn/minipage in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

Please take the following MWE into account :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Array A :} 
\vspace{\baselineskip}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\small\sf}p{3cm}p{1cm}XX}
\toprule
col1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
Everything should be on the same line and this is fine
\end{minipage}}\\

\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\textbf{Array B :} 
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\small\sf}p{3cm}p{1cm}XX}
\toprule
col1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
Everything should be on the same line and this is fine
\end{minipage}}\\

a & b & c & d\\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Why is the text cut at half the space in array B ? I would like it to take all the space available on the line, like in array A. Note that I'm using `minipage` inside my column cells because they may contains `itemize` or `tabular`.

Comment: It should be `\multicolumn{3}{l}...` I guess.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi putting `l` will end up in my text not being wrapped at the end of the cell if it's too long.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159009 As you can see there and in karlkoellers answer, this is not easily possible. Just set your minipage to 8.5 cm or leave it away completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tabularx` documentation suggests to not use the `X` specifier in `\multicolumn`s and also to not use `\multicolumn` entries which cross any `X` column.

If you really want to do that, you'd better use a `p` column and you don't need a `minipage`. Also, without a `\noindent`, using `\linewidth` exceeds the margins.

Last, but not least, use `\sffamily` instead of the deprecated (in LaTeX) `\sf`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Array A :}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\small\sffamily}p{3cm}p{1cm}XX}
\toprule
col1 & \multicolumn{3}{p{8cm}}{Everything can't fit on the same line because it's too long}\\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\textbf{Array B :}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\small\sffamily}p{3cm}p{1cm}XX}
\toprule
col1 & \multicolumn{3}{p{8cm}}{Everything can't fit on the same line because it's too long}\\
a & b & c & d\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. How did you find the `8cm` value ? I don't have the same margins, so if there's a technique to actually calculate this value easily, I'm very interrested.

Comment: @NNzz You're welcome. The value of `8.2cm` seems to be the maximum not to exceed the margin (found by trial)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid guessing the required length by noticing you want to span 2 `X` columns, a 3cm `p` column and two intercolumn gaps each of width `2\tabcolsep`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Array A :}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\small\sffamily}p{3cm}p{1cm}XX}
\toprule
col1 & \multicolumn{3}{p{8cm}}{Everything can't fit on the same line because it's too long}\\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\textbf{Array B :}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\small\sffamily}p{3cm}p{1cm}XX}
\toprule
col1 & \multicolumn{3}{X}{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+4\tabcolsep+3cm\relax
Everything can't fit on the same line because it's too long}\\
a & b & c & d\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```